# Tensorflow with verbs support

Tags: tensorflow, grpc

When TensorFlow is built with verbs support, I believe there are only two ways to exercise distributed learning:

1. gRPC + verbs protocol
2. Horovod

Do we always need to use IPoIB when exercising gRPC + verbs protocol? Or can TF somehow understand the IB adapter on the system and route the traffic accordingly?

I am just wondering if there is a pure IB way of doing distributed learning other than Horovod.